# Auto increment an element value when a URL is hit using API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to DRF, so apologies if it's a trivial question.

I want to create an API endpoint to auto-increment the value of a column in the database, whenever a specified URL is hit.

For instance:

In the **models.py** file I have:

```py
class User(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=250)
  error= models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
```

How should I write a class-based API View and Function-based API View that whenever the associated URL hits, the value of error increments by 1?

In the URL the ID of the row should also be passed such as:
`localhost:8000/users/error/<id>`

Upon hitting the above URL the value of the error for user 2 should be increased by one.
The below is the functional view I wrote but, it is not working properly.
ERROR1: If the URL is hit and the `id` is not present in the database then also the response is `201`.

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly])
def updateClick(request, uri_id):

    p = Url_data.objects.filter(uri_id=uri_id).update(clicks=F('clicks')+1)
    print("PPPP: ", p)
    url_obj = Url_data.objects.all()
    serializer = ClickSerializer(url_obj, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.status_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define an URL pattern with:

```
path('/users/error/<int:pk>/', some_view, name='increment-errors'),
```

This view can look like:

```
from django.db.models import F

def my_view(request, pk):
    User.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(error=F('error')+1)
    # …
```

where the `…` part should return a `HttpResponse`.

Normally GET requests should not alter entities, so such views usually should be triggered with a POST request. We can restrict the view to a POST request with:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def my_view(request, pk):
    User.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(error=F('error')+1)
    # …
```